# In a For Loop in Python 3, is the right boundary inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, modulo

I am running this code in Python:

```
#Finding prime numbers
for n in range(2, 10):
   for x in range(2, n):
      if n % x == 0:
        print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
        break
# loop fell through without finding a factor
   else:
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

The output for this is as follows:

```
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

Let's assume the following iteration is going on:

```
n=3, x=n
```

**What is the value of n%x ?**

If it is `== 0` then why do we not get

```
print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
```

Comment: Did you try it? And you *do* seem to get that. Isn't that what `9 equals 3 * 3` is?

Comment: I was asking for n=3 not n=9. The whole problem was that I did not know the brackets excluded the last number. Resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what is the value of `n%n`, it is zero, because n is always divisible by n and % is the division remainder operator. That's why the loop in your code is going for x from 2 to n - 1 (that's what `range(2, n)` is doing - its last argument is not inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator gets the remainder. So if you do 5%2, the result is equivalent to if you divide 5 by 2 to get 2 with 1 left over, so 5%2 => 1.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `n % n` is 0. In your given example, `n=3` and `x=n`, the statement

```
print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
```

would print

```
3 equals 3*1
```

The thing with your code is just that it isn't ever comparing `n` to itself. Look at your loops:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        ...
```

The first loop is from 2 to 10, *exclusive*, which means 2 through 9. The second loop is from 2 to `n`, *exclusive*. If `n == 2`, that means that the second loop *doesn't run at all*. If `n == 3`, the second loop only runs once, on `x = 2`. And et cetera.

Comment: Thank you ! Need to look into exclusive and inclusive bracketing.